# Picard iteration for $x'(t)=2tx^2$, $x(0)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem, $x'(t)=2tx^2$, $x(0)=1$.
It was asked to find the first four approximations through the Picard iteration.

that is, for $x'=f(x)$, $x(0)=x_0$:
$$u_0(t)=x_0$$
$$u_{k+1}(t)=x_0+\int\limits_0^tf(u_k(s))ds$$
My question is, the above question is not in the format for the Picard iteration. So how should I rewrite it as $x'=f(x)$

Comment: Mh, it *is* in the desired format for application of Picard's method. Maybe your formula is not...

Comment: @YvesDaoust well.. then what should I take as $f(x)$?

Comment: Proofread your formulas. Where did you get them ?

Comment: you need $x' = f(t, x)$ instead of $x' = f(x)$.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Then in my case $f(t,x)=2tx^2$ ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=2tx^2$$
$$\frac{dx}{2tdt}=x^2$$
Change of variable :
$$T=t^2\quad\implies\quad dT=2tdt$$
$$\frac{dx}{dT}=x^2$$
$$x'(T)=x^2$$
You have the required form $x'(T)=f(x)$ with the function $x(T)$ instead of $x(t)$.

Don't confuse the symbol "prime" with respect to $T$ instead of with respect to $t$.

Proceed to the Picard iteration for $x(T)$. Then replace $T$ by $t^2$ in order to transform your result for $x(t)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation